# Multiple instances of same calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and trying to create an on-line score tracker for a card game I play called Hand and Foot. The rules are this, 3 teams play 4 games, the team with the most points at the end wins. I have created a calculator for 1 person for 1 game, but when I duplicate it for the 11 more instances I need, the calculations stop working which I believe has to do with the getElementById not registering with the multiple instances in the html. I would be grateful suggestions on a more elegant way to create instances of this calculator on the same page without having to change the IDs of each field for each play and each game. check out my code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scooter3030/h7u1kex3/)

```
 <div class="P1G1">
   <h1>Game 1</h1>

<form id="calcP1G1">

<h2>Neccessary Piles</h2>

    <table>
        <td>Clean</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input id="necCleanP1G1" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="500">
        </td>
        <td>Dirty</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input id="necDirtyP1G1" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="300">
        </td>
        <td>Sevens</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input id="necSevenP1G1" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="5000">
        </td>
        <td>Fives</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input id="necFiveP1G1" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="3000">
        </td>
        <td>Wilds</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input id="necWildP1G1" type="checkbox" class="addon" value="2500">
        </td>
        <td id="necTotalP1G1" style="display:none"></td>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="pile-header">Clean Piles</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="input-number">
                <input id="cleanP1G1" type="text" value="0" oninput="calculate()" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="result-number">
                <input id="resultCleanP1G1" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pile-header">Dirty Piles</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="input-number">
                <input id="dirtyP1G1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" value="0" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="result-number">
                <input id="resultDirtyP1G1" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pile-header">Red 3s</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="input-number">
                <input id="redThreeP1G1" oninput="calculate()" value="0" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="result-number">
                <input id="resultRedThreeP1G1" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pile-header">Card Count</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="input-number">
                <input id="cardsP1G1" oninput="calculate()" value="0" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="result-number">
                <input id="resultCardP1G1" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pile-header">Total</td>
            <td class="result-number">
                <input id="resultTotalP1G1" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function updateTotal() {
var add = 0;
var form = document.getElementById("calcP1G1");
var checkboxes = form.getElementsByClassName('addon');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        add += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value, 10);
    }
}


var amount = document.getElementById("necTotalP1G1").innerHTML = add;
}
document.getElementById("calcP1G1").addEventListener('change', updateTotal);
// Run it once at startup
updateTotal();

function calculate() {

var topCards = document.getElementById("necTotalP1G1").innerHTML;

var cleanBox = document.getElementById("cleanP1G1").value;
var totalClean = document.getElementById("resultCleanP1G1");

var resultClean = cleanBox * 500;
totalClean.value = resultClean;

//---------------------//

var dirtyBox = document.getElementById("dirtyP1G1").value;

var totalDirty = document.getElementById("resultDirtyP1G1");

var resultDirty = dirtyBox * 300;
totalDirty.value = resultDirty;

//---------------------//

var redThreeBox = document.getElementById("redThreeP1G1").value;

var totalRedThree = document.getElementById("resultRedThreeP1G1");

var resultRedThree = redThreeBox * 100;
totalRedThree.value = resultRedThree;


//---------------------//

var cardBox = document.getElementById("cardsP1G1").value;
var totalCard = cardBox;
document.getElementById("resultCardP1G1").value = totalCard;



//---------------------//



var total = parseInt(resultDirty) + parseInt(resultClean) +   parseInt(resultRedThree) + parseInt(totalCard) + parseInt(topCards);
document.getElementById("resultTotalP1G1").value = total;
}
document.getElementById("calcP1G1").addEventListener('change', calculate);
// Run it once at startup
calculate();
```

Comment: You can't just duplicate the same HTML as your elements are retrieved by ID.  It wouldn't know which one to grab.  Your best options are to make your code more dynamic (ie: you can pass in IDs via a function so that you can have multiple copies of the HTML with unique identifiers) or you might be able to do something with frames that all load the same page, but honestly I am not leaning towards that as an approach.  Bottom line think more generically, make your code re-useable for multiple copies of the "widget".